# TSQL Pivot 4 value columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

In SQL Server 2008 I'm trying to 'pivot' the table format below to wide format using the Period column (in the real data there are 5 different Periods).

I've searched but not yet found a solution to this. I've referred to https://www.tangrainc.com/blog/2009/01/pivoting-on-multiple-columns/#comment-504 but cannot translate the logic to >2 value columns - which I need.

Any thoughts? You may have guessed I'm no SQL expert. Using SQL Server 2008.

Thanks,
Chris

ps. first S/O post!

Trying to get from a flat table:

[image]

to a wide table:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *conditional* aggregation:

```
select Cat, Dept,
       sum(case when Period = 'LW' then New else 0 end) as [Net LW],
       sum(case when Period = 'LY' then New else 0 end) as [Net LY],
       sum(case when Period = 'LW' then Gross else 0 end) as [Gross LW],
       sum(case when Period = 'LY' then Gross else 0 end) as [Gross LY],
       sum(case when Period = 'LW' then Profit else 0 end) as [Profit LW],
       sum(case when Period = 'LY' then Profit else 0 end) as [Profit LY],
       sum(case when Period = 'LW' then Units else 0 end) as [Units LW],
       sum(case when Period = 'LY' then Units else 0 end) as [Units LY]
from table t
group by Cat, Dept;
```

Comment: Argh is it really that simple?! Thanks Yogesh - I'll give it a try now and come back if any issues.

Comment: only thing you may want to be careful of is null aggregation. May want to add an else 0 to the case statements to make sure that NULL settings in the DB do no affect your calculation. Most times this will not happen but always better to be safe than sorry

Comment: @SFrejofsky. . . That is very important that i forgot.